# How to add to a list without overwriting it when calling a method for the second time?

Tags: python, list

Here's an example of the code im trying to implement:

```
def notes():            
    print "\nPlease enter any notes:"
    global texts
    texts = []
    if not texts:
        print "no notes exist."
        write_note()
    else:
        print "this note already exists"

def write_note():
    while True:
        global txt
        txt = raw_input(">>> ")
        if not txt:
            break
        else:
            texts.append(txt)
    print "\nNote(s) added to report."
    notes_menu()

def print_note():
    new_report.write("\nNotes:")
    for txt in texts:
        new_report.write("\n-%r" % txt)
    print "Note Printed to %r. Goodbye!" % file_name
    exit(0)
```

My goal here is to make it so if/when "notes()" is called a second(or ad infinitum) time the new inputs are added to "texts" list and dont overwrite the list. I tried attempting to at least determine if the list was empty whenever "notes()" is called. But every time I do, regardless of how many items ive created in "texts" during the previous calling, it always prints "no notes exist."

I'm kind of at a loss at this point. I've looked into the dictionary function but im not sure how to incorporate it into this code. Anyone have any advice/suggestions?

Comment: Why are you making `txt` a global?

Comment: This looks like it would be better organized as methods of a class called `Notes`, with a `self.texts` attribute. However, I'm a bit too confused about what it's doing (It looks like when `note()` is called, but any notes already exist, it will say `Please enter any notes:\nThis note already exists` without even allowing any input.) And it's not clear what `new_report` or `notes_menu` are.

Comment: @blender it gets used later in the print method.

Comment: @grc Then how does texts get defined as a list?

Comment: @david The "this note already exists" is just a place holder at the moment. eventually it will call the write_note method and add more items to "Texts" instead of overwriting the list and starting over.

Comment: Remove `texts = []` from `notes` and place same code at global scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comments that suggest a better design would be to create a class that contains the texts. However, with respect to the code as it stands, it appears to me that `texts = []` should be in the main code, outside `notes()`, so that the line is only ever run once.

Comment: This helps! I moved those two lines to the main body and the test worked! But now the question is, instead of printing "this already exists" if theres already items in the list. How do i get it to add to the list without overwriting it?

Comment: You're already using `texts.append(txt)`, which should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

without changing too much of what you have above, can I suggest a function that simply requests a new note, and appends the note to the existing list:

```
>>> notes = []
>>> def write_note(notes):
...     while True:
...         new_note = raw_input('>>> ')
...         if not new_note:
...             break
...         else:
...             notes.append(new_note)
```

Does this do what you are after?

Answer (score 0):

When you call texts = [] you set text to an empty list, blanking out any items set earlier.  Removing that line should help.

Also, I think may you want to use the .extend() function.  Append adds an item on to the end of a list, i.e.:

```
>>li = [1,2,3]
>>li2 = [4,5,6]
>>li.append(li2)
li = [1,2,3,[4,5,6]]
```

Where as extend() concatenates two lists:

```
>>li = [1,2,3]
>>li2 = [4,5,6]
>>li.extend(li2)
li = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

This can be found on [dive into python](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/lists.html)

Comment: The difference between `append` and `extend` is important when appending a list to another list, as shown, but in this case the issue is appending a string `txt` to a list `texts`. `append()` is the appropriate method to use in this case because using `extend()` with a string parameter first breaks the string into letters and then appends the letters to the list.